# Solve equation $1+\sin^2\theta=3\sin\theta\cos\theta \text { (given } \tan71 ^{\circ}34^{\prime}=3) $

Tags: trigonometry

Solve equation $1+\sin^2\theta=3\sin\theta\cos\theta \text { (given } \tan71 ^{\circ}34^{\prime}=3)  $

My attempt is as follows:-

$$1-2\sin\theta\cos\theta+\sin^2\theta-\sin\theta\cos\theta=0$$
$$\left(\sin\theta-\cos\theta\right)^2+\sin\theta\left(\sin\theta-\cos\theta\right)=0$$
$$\left(\sin\theta-\cos\theta\right)(2\sin\theta-\cos\theta)=0$$
$$\tan\theta=1 \text { or } \tan\theta=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\theta=n\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}$$

For $\tan\theta=\dfrac{1}{2} \text { how to make use of given condition } \tan71 ^{\circ}34^{\prime}=3$

Answer (score 2):

Use $3=\frac{1+\frac12}{1-1\cdot\frac12}=\tan(45^\circ+\theta)$.

Comment: but how did you do that, guessing or something else

Comment: @user3290550 I solved $3=\frac{k+\frac12}{1-\frac12 k}$ so I could use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities).

Answer (score 0):

As $1+2+3=1\cdot2\cdot3$

$\arctan1+\arctan2+\arctan 3=n\pi$

using [Show $\tan(x)+\tan(y)+\tan(z) = \tan(x) \tan(y) \tan(z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395630/show-tanx-tany-tanz-tanx-tany-tanz)

As $\arctan(u)<\dfrac\pi2$

$n=1$

Now $\arctan1=\dfrac\pi4$

$\arctan2+\arctan\dfrac12=\arctan2+$arccot$2=\dfrac\pi2$

See [Are $\mathrm{arccot}(x)$ and $\arctan(1/x)$ the same function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304399/are-mathrmarccotx-and-arctan1-x-the-same-function)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197393/why-does-tan-11-tan-12-tan-13-pi/197397#197397